# DotCover Cobertura or OpenCover XML

Tags: code-coverage, cobertura, opencover, dotcover

I have a dotcover coverage report generated using dotcover.exe.
I want to integrate the report in Jenkins and show the coverage.
How can I generate a cobertura or openclover xml from it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ReportGenerator](https://reportgenerator.io/) for that.

First, install reportgenerator as dotnet global tool:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
```

Second, dotCover report should be in DetailedXML format, it has file paths that needed in Cobertura.

Then, run reportgenerator to convert to desired format, like:

```
reportgenerator -reports:./dotCover.Output.xml -targetdir:. -reporttypes:Cobertura
```

As a result, you'll have Cobertura.xml file.